# cjw_newsletter the cronjobs to send mails is broken

Tags: php, sendmail, ezpublish

I have a problem with the extension cjw_newsletter. since two days cronjobs does not work I get the following message.

Can you help me please

`END: cjw_newsletter_mailqueue_create
Completing extension/cjw_newsletter/cronjobs/cjw_newsletter_mailqueue_create.php at: 03/02/2014 09:30
Elapsed time: 00:01:03`

Running extension/cjw_newsletter/cronjobs/cjw_newsletter_mailqueue_process.php at: 03/02/2014 09:30
**Cronjob part locked by other process: 14053**
Completing extension/cjw_newsletter/cronjobs/cjw_newsletter_mailqueue_process.php at: 03/02/2014 09:30
Elapsed time: 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cronjob is still running ; it is locked by ezpublish.
Have a look at var/[storage folder]/cache/ezmutex, you should see there somes files. If it is the cas, you have a cronjob still running.
You just have to wait till the end of the cronjob.
If you can't, kill the process and delete the file in ezmutex.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your previous cron has crashed.

CjwNewsletter stores all sending process in "cjwnl_edition_send" table.
You should have a row with status at value "2". Simply put this status to 1 and run again the process cron.

I don't have found another solution.